# my req.session does not counting up and stays same when i refreshed

Tags: node.js, session

i added req.session.views to check either my session is working or not, but when i refreshed. it's always detect me come to that page as first time.

i tried req.session.save, but its also not working. here is my code.

```
const app = express()
var session = require('express-session')
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

app.use(cors())
const mc = mysql.createConnection({
    host    : 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx',
    user    : 'user',
    password: '',
    database: 'my_db',
    multipleStatements: true
})

mc.connect()

var sessionStore = new MySQLStore({}, mc);

app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(session({
    name: 'mytesting',
    key: 'JSESSIONID',
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}))

app.get('/', function (req, res){   
    if (req.session.views) {
        req.session.views++
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        res.write('<p>views: ' + req.session.views + '</p>')
        res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (req.session.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
        req.session.save()
        res.end()
      } else {
        req.session.views = 1
        req.session.save()
        res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
      }
})
```

the view should be counted up. but it always show "welcome to the session demo. refresh!"

i'm stuck on this for weeks. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I'm not sure why.. but when I change:

```
res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
```

To:

```
res.end('<html>welcome to the session demo. refresh!');
```

It works. Implying that the browsers require an `<html>` tag in order to accept cookies?